# celldblclick does not fired if the cell contains HTML extjs 3.4.0

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the following EditorGridPanel on extJS:

http://jsfiddle.net/VDFsq/1/

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
  var myData = [[ '<SPAN STYLE=\"text-align:Left;font-family:Segoe UI;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:12;color:#000000;\"><P STYLE=\"font-family:Arial;font-size:16;margin:0 0 0 0;\"><SPAN><SPAN>HTML </SPAN></SPAN><SPAN STYLE=\"font-weight:bold;color:#FF0000;\"><SPAN>FORMAT</SPAN></SPAN><SPAN><SPAN> TEST<BR />TEST</SPAN></SPAN></P></SPAN>', "lisa@simpsons.com", "555-111-1224"],
                [ 'Bart', "bart@simpsons.com", "555-222-1234"],
                [ 'Homer', "home@simpsons.com", "555-222-1244"],
                [ 'Marge', "marge@simpsons.com", "555-222-1254"]];

  var store = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
    fields:[ {
      name: 'name'
    },
    {
      name: 'email'
    },
    {
      name: 'phone'
    }],
    data: myData
  });
  var grid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
    renderTo: 'grid-container',
    columns:[ {
      header: 'Name',
      dataIndex: 'name', 
        width:200
    }
    ],
    store: store,
    frame: true,
    height: 240,
    width: 500,
      enableColumnMove :false,
            stripeRows: true,
            enableHdMenu: false,
            border: true,
            autoScroll:true,
            clicksToEdit: true,
    title: 'HTML in Grid Cell',
    iconCls: 'icon-grid',
      sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({
      singleSelect: true
    })
  });

    grid.on({
        celldblclick: function() {alert(1);}
        });
});
```

the problem is, when the gridCell contains HTML data (which is my situation) when you double click on the cell with html the grid does not fire the event celldblclick.

in my application I need to display that kind of html in the grid.

how can fix this problem? anyway to bubble the event from the html to the grid?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is some limits to dom tree deep inside your structure. I think it is not good idea to put html into grid - if you can unify it structure - may be templates would be more useful.

Try this instead of your HTML:

```
 "<div ondblclick=\"alert('1!')\">1<div ondblclick=\"alert('2!')\">2<div ondblclick=\"alert('3!')\">3<div ondblclick=\"alert('4!')\">4</div>3</div>2</div>1</div>"
```

Event inheritance works fine in this HTML, but works only 2 levels deep in your EXt example.

NOTE: if you try

```
 grid.on('rowdblclick', function(eventGrid, rowIndex, e) {
     console.log('double click');
 }, this);
```

you will not get problem (but, obviously, you can dblclick only rows in this way)